# to show an alert once user backs to a page

Tags: javascript, html, window

There are two pages, and I want to show an alert on the first page when the user comes back from second page to first page.

I know how to go back to first page by: `window.location.href`

and also by: `window.history.back()`.

But I don't know how to show an alert once it's backed?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37838430/detect-if-page-is-load-from-back-button

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve it using `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`.

// Page 1

```
const visited = localStorage.getItem("visited")

if(visited) alert("//Do something here, why you came back")

else localStorage.setItem("visited", "visited")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give the url a parameter and use it to check whether an alert message should be fired.

For example: `window.location.search -> '?visited=true'`