# Viewstate does not become null after coming from another page

Tags: asp.net

I have one page,inside that page have 2 button.Inside one button click event,assigning viewstate value(I saved one string value to viewstate ex: AllItems),in second button click event,I am checking that whether that viewstate is null or not null,if not null insert record into database.End of button2 click event making viewstate null.button2 event have try and catch block.If any error occur,inside catch block making viewstate null and sending user to Errorpage.If user use browser back button,user find viewstate not null,and getting that value(AllItems).How it possible?How to handle that?

Comment: If you formatted your question, and showed some code that illustrated the problem (and only the problem) - I think you'll have more luck with getting answers. But ..... if I understand, I think the core of the issue is that viewstate is saved on the page itself in a hidden field and therefore accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer Below link

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37004614/5897242

normally page load not happens when we click browser back button, above links gives you solution for that.