# Clear Session in ASP .NET MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a question. I work in ASP .NET MVC 5 . I want to prevent is that , after logging out , then I click the back navigation button , I don't want to go back to the previous page . Is there anyone who can help me? I use Session Clear and Abandon methods and FormsAuthentication's SignOut method.But this not sole my problem.

Comment: the forms auth token is stored in cookie not in session. Try clearing the form auth cookie as mentioned here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412300/formsauthentication-signout-does-not-log-the-user-out

Comment: `Session.Abandon` should work correct. BUT, only when you use sessions to store data in. What method do you use to store your data?

Comment: you need to prevent browser to go back or clear history from browser cache.

Comment: what do you use cookie within session?

Comment: Do you use checkauthorization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should use your OutputCache action method

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 1)]
```

or

Global.asax.cs you add

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{                
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1));
    Response.Cache.SetNoStore();                                 
}
```

Do session check in action method

```
if (Session["xxx"] == null)
{
     return View("aaaa");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - @sedevel

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the browser caches the data, you have to clear the browser cache by setting some headers in the page response.

You can do that using the answer of this question [How to refresh page on back button click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20899274/how-to-refresh-page-on-back-button-click)

Answer (score 1):

[See the Image]
1)sign out the user
2)put [Authorize] attribute before Controller

This will redirect the user to login page