# How can I detect if my page was "resurrected" with the back button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser

When I push the back button my browser seems to load the page from some kind of cache and seems to re-fill some of the input fields with the values they had before I moved to another page by clicking a link. However, the site's state seems to be messed up because it has a bunch of "impossible" bugs that only appear when it's re-visited via pressing the back button.

How can I find out if this happened and then reload the page or prevent this from happening altogether? (Like forcing a reload each time the browser displays the page anew?)

Comment: Possibly a pop state question? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popstate

Comment: check this page out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20899274/how-to-refresh-page-on-back-button-click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check to see if the page was accessed via the browser history, like this

```
if (!!window.performance && window.performance.navigation.type === 2) {
            // value 2 means "The page was accessed by navigating into the history"
            console.log('Reloading');
            window.location.reload(); // reload whole page

        }
```

Comment: in what interval or at what event should this be checked?

Comment: I think you can just put it at the top of your file, only needs to be checked once

Comment: but will the top of my file be executed when the site is visited with the back button and not properly reloaded?

Comment: It seems to be for me, i'm not sure about all browsers though