# Update $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] when pressing browser's back button (reload page)

Tags: php, html, safari

In Safari 10.1.1 the browser's back button does not reload the target page, so `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` is not changed.

Is there a way to reload the target page when the browser's back button is pressed. I tried the following:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
header("Pragma: no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
header("Expires: 0"); // Proxies.
```

This does not work.

Background: I try to build a reliable page history in PHP, but how can I, if the browser's back button does not trigger anything on the server?

Thank you!

Comment: What's the purpose behind building a reliable page history? What are you trying to accomplish? You could do something with AJAX, I suppose, but *why*? Have you considered using JavaScript's History API for navigation?

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I try to break it down:
I have a start page and a second page. I move from the start page to the second page and back. If I enter the start page from the second page a different content (a different operation on the server) should be shown/triggered.
What would be the right way to accomplish this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In your case the browser does not call the server AT ALL.
In most cases the browsers will just show the "local/cached" version of the previous page and won't initiate a connection to the server.

You might find some javascript solutions here to force the reload :
[How to force reloading a page when using browser back button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43043113/how-to-force-reloading-a-page-when-using-browser-back-button) or here [How to refresh page on back button click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20899274/how-to-refresh-page-on-back-button-click)

The most relevant part being the use of the `windows.performance` object.

```
if(!!window.performance && window.performance.navigation.type === 2)
{
    window.location.reload();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought some "no-cache" command (on PHP or HTML site) could stop the caching so the browser must initiate a connection to the server. Is there nothing like that?

Comment: The headers example you provided is already good and there is nothing more you could add, so if the browser still keeps a cached version the JS is the only workaround.
Did you apply thoose headers on every pages (the current and the "previous" before the previous was loaded) ?

Comment: Yes, the header is applied to every page. Thank you!