# How to force HTML to reload when returning from another page

Tags: javascript, timer, onload

The HTML links to another page that may update what should show on screen. When the the page returns to my program the program is not reloaded and what is shown is no longer completely valid. (Yes, I know some times the opposite happens.) The only possible solution I can think of is to set the timer to trigger a reload. However, I don't want the event to be triggered until after the HTML/JAVASCRIPT regains control (will the browser do that for me?)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to refresh page on back button click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20899274/how-to-refresh-page-on-back-button-click)

Answer (score 0):

You could use window.parent to access page and refresh it from your second page.