# success messages shows again when i go back through broswer

Tags: laravel, flash-message

I'm using sweet alert for success messages
once i submit the form and redirect to back page its shows success message but after that i go again to that page and just come back without submitting form its shows success message again.

This problem only appear when i submit form once other wise after reloading the page i go to that page and come back its working fine:

Blade file:

```
@extends('layout/header')
@include('layout/sidebar')
<div id="page-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <h2 class="page_heading1">EFTERÅT</h2>
            <p class="page_heading">Här är 5 frågor om hur du efter avslutad kontakt ser på din situation. 1 är mycket
                negativt/dålig t och 10 är mycket positivt/bra Ange en siffra genom att markera på linjen.</p>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="left_situationen">
                    @if(session()->has('message'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success">
                            {{ session()->get('message') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif
                    <form class="form-horizontal fyl_form" action="/efterat/{{request()->route('id')}}" method="post">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="range-wraph" style="width: 100%;">
                            <label class="custom-range_motet">1. Hur mår du i allmänhet just nu? <br>
                                <input type="range" name="efterat1" value="{{ old('efterat1') }}" class="range" min="1" max="10"></label>
                            <output class="bubble"></output>
                        </div>
                        <div class="range-wraph" style="width: 100%;">
                            <label class="custom-range_situationen">2. Hur upplever du nu dina
                                behov/svårigheter/besvär?<br>
                                <input type="range" name="efterat2" value="{{ old('efterat2') }}" class="range" min="1" max="10"></label>
                            <output class="bubble"></output>
                        </div>
                        <div class="range-wraph" style="width: 100%;">
                            <label class="custom-range_situationen">3. Är du nöjd med den hjälp/de åtgärder du fick?<br>
                                <input type="range" name="efterat3" value="{{ old('efterat3') }}" class="range" min="1" max="10"></label>
                            <output class="bubble"></output>
                        </div>
                        <div class="range-wraph" style="width: 100%;">
                            <label class="custom-range_situationen">4. Hur mycket har hjälpen/åtgärderna bidragit till
                                en förbättring?<br>
                                <input type="range" name="efterat4" value="{{ old('efterat4') }}" class="range" min="1" max="10"></label>
                            <output class="bubble"></output>
                        </div>
                        <div class="range-wraph" style="width: 100%;">
                            <label class="custom-range_situationen">5. Skulle du ha önskat någon annan hjälp?<br>
                                <input type="range" name="efterat5" value="{{ old('efterat5') }}" class="range" min="1" max="10"></label>
                            <output class="bubble"></output>
                        </div>
                        <div class="range-wraph" style="width: 100%;">

                            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="efterat_select" 
                                       value="Nej" checked> Nej </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="range-wraph" style="width: 100%;">

                            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="efterat_select" 
                                       value="ja" > Ja, ange vilken hjälp och
                                varför</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="range-wraph" style="width: 100%;">
                            <textarea  value="{{ old('efterat1_description') }}" name="efterat1_description" class="form-control"></textarea>
                            @if ($errors->has('efterat1_description'))
                                <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('efterat1_description') }}</span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                        <div class="range-wraph" style="width: 100%;">
                            <p class="bottom_text">Har du några andra synpunkter?</p>
                            <textarea   name="efterat2_description" value="{{ old('efterat2_description') }}" class="form-control"></textarea>
                            <input type="hidden" name="client_id" value="{{$client_id}}">
                            @if ($errors->has('efterat2_description'))
                                <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('efterat2_description') }}</span>
                            @endif
                            <p class="bottom_text">Tack för dina svar</p>
                            <button type="submit" style="width: 100px;" class="btn btn-primary">Skicka</button>
                    </form>
              
                    <script>
                        const allRanges = document.querySelectorAll(".range-wraph");
                        allRanges.forEach(wrap => {
                            const range = wrap.querySelector(".range");
                            const bubble = wrap.querySelector(".bubble");

                            range.addEventListener("input", () => {
                                setBubble(range, bubble);
                            });
                            setBubble(range, bubble);
                        });

                        function setBubble(range, bubble) {
                            const val = range.value;
                            const min = range.min ? range.min : 0;
                            const max = range.max ? range.max : 100;
                            const newVal = Number(((val - min) * 100) / (max - min));
                            bubble.innerHTML = val;

                            // Sorta magic numbers based on size of the native UI thumb
                            bubble.style.left = `calc(${newVal}% + (${8 - newVal * 0.15}px))`;
                        }
                    </script>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</div>
<!-- /#page-wrapper -->
</div>
<!-- /#wrapper -->
<!-- jQuery -->
@include('layout/footer')
```

Controller code:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Efterat;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use RealRashid\SweetAlert\Facades\Alert;


class EfteratController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('preventBackHistory');
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index($id)
    {
        $client_data = $id;
        return view('efterat')->with('client_id', $client_data);

    }

    public function store(Request $request, $id)
    {
      
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'efterat1' => 'required',
            'efterat2' => 'required',
            'efterat3' => 'required',
            'efterat4' => 'required',
            'efterat5' => 'required',
            'efterat_select' => 'required|in:ja,Nej',
            'efterat1_description' => 'nullable|max:150|required_if:efterat_select,ja',
            'efterat2_description' => 'nullable|max:150|required_if:efterat_select,ja',
            'client_id' => 'required',
            'handler_id' => 'nullable',
        ],
            [
                'efterat1_description.required_if' => 'fältet krävs när valet är ja',
                'efterat2_description.required_if' => 'fältet krävs när valet är ja',
                'efterat1_description.max' => 'Beskrivningen får inte vara större än 150 tecken!',
                'efterat2_description.max' => 'Beskrivningen får inte vara större än 150 tecken!',
            ]);
        Efterat::create($request->all());
        Alert::success('Framgång', 'Framgångsrikt skickat');
        if (Auth::user()->role == "clients")
        {
            return redirect()->to('om/'.$id);
        }else{
            return redirect()->to('instalningar/'.$id);
        
        }
    }

    public function efteratreports($id)
    {
        $data = Efterat::where('client_id', $id)->get();
        return view('efteratreports')->with('efteratdata', $data);
    }

    public function efteratgraph($id)
    {

        $data = Efterat::where('client_id', $id)->get();

        return view('efteratgraph')->with('efteratgraph', $data);
    }
}
```

Routes for this:

```
Route::get('/efterat/{id}', 'EfteratController@index');
Route::post('/efterat/{id}', 'EfteratController@store')->name('efterat');
/* eftrat reports and graph */
Route::get('/efteratreports/{id}', 'EfteratController@efteratreports');
Route::get('/efteratgraph/{id}', 'EfteratController@efteratgraph');
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, when the user clicks the **back button** in the browser, the browser tries to display the contents of the previous page without **reloading** it. So it's likely not Laravel **flashing** to the session again, but the browser trying to help you out by **caching** the page for you.

Comment: I understand this but any solution to stop this

Comment: @farooq, this is a browser side issue. Not related to Laravel. You can disable the back button  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381563/how-to-stop-browser-back-button-using-javascript or you can force the page to reload when click back button https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43043113/how-to-force-reloading-a-page-when-using-browser-back-button

Comment: These links : i dont want to stop user go back i just stop the browser to using previous page content

Comment: @farooq, then reload the page when user click the back button,  there are lot of possible way here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20899274/how-to-refresh-page-on-back-button-click mark this answer as accepted if it really helped your solution