# Getting the content of dynamic div after clicking the back button

Tags: javascript, html

I have a couple of divs that I created dynamically, which are added for documents that the user already seen.

```
doc_html.innerHTML = '<div id=' + doc_id + ' class="seen-doc"> <h5>You\'ve already seen this document.</h5></div>' + doc_html.innerHTML;
```

I also have this code to run when the user clicks the back button while on document, to return to the main menu. (I got this from  https://stackoverflow.com/a/19196020/1122229)

```
<input type="hidden" id="refresh" value="no">
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
        var $input = $('#refresh');
        $input.val() == 'yes' ? update_seen_docs() : $input.val('yes');
    });
</script>
```

What I need `update_seen_docs()` to do is look at the dynamic divs that I created earlier (with id equal to`doc_id`) and check if they exist or not. I already have the list of `doc_id`s that I want to check their existence. What I need is a way to check whether these dynamic div been created successfully by my earlier code.

I have tried putting this in my `update_seen_docs()`

```
doc_html = document.getElementById(doc_id);
if (doc_html){
    # do stuff
}
```

but since the divs with `doc_id` are dynamic, `doc_html` is always `null`.

Comment: `id` should be unique..Are they unique in your case ? If there are many `id` attributes havins similar value, `getElementById` will return first matched element...

Comment: the `id`s are unique. `getElementById` returns null because the divs are dynamic and not explicitly written in the html.

Comment: If you are trying to access elements after they are appended they it can not be null...