# Use history.js with jQuery dynamic content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, history.js

I have a shop which uses dynamic content. Users can click on checkboxes to view products of specific categories. For this I am using jQuery to get products from another php file (works fine).

shop.php:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="category_btn" name="cat" id="category-books" value="books">
<input type="checkbox" class="category_btn" name="cat" id="category-dvds" value="dvds">
...    
<div id="allProducts">
   Load dynamic content with jQuery here...
</div>
```

loadProducts.php:

```
<?php
$categories = $_POST['categories'];
$productsData = load_products($categories);

for ($i = 0; $i < $amount; $i++) {?>
    <div class="singleproduct">
        <a href="product.php?id=<?php echo $productsData[$i]['ID'] ?>"><img
                    src="images/<?php echo get_image($productsData[$i]['ID']) ?>"
                    alt=""></a>
        <p class="prod-title"><?php echo $productsData[$i]['title'] ?></p>
    </div>
<?php }?>
```

jQuery code (shop.php):

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var checkedCats = [];
        $(".category_btn:checked").each(function() {
            checkedCats.push($(this).val());
        });

        $(".category_btn").click(function () {
            var arraydata = {"categories[]" : checkedCats};
            $.post('loadProducts.php', arraydata, function (data) {
                var test = $('#allProducts').html(data);
            });
        });
    };
</script>
```

Now if a user clicks on a product to view details and then returns to shop.php by using the back-button, he will see the main page of the shop with no dynamic loaded content. Is it possible to save the last view with marked checkboxes and loaded products? 
I think history.js is the solution, but I have no idea how to do this. Maybe somebody can help...

Comment: It's a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046184/reload-the-site-when-reached-via-browsers-back-button go there.

Comment: It is not. I am not adding any gets to the url so reloading the page does nothing.

Comment: When the back button is pushed, the website goes to it's original state.  The URL I linked mentions how to force a reload so that you can see your items.  I don't know if history.js can solve your problem, I looked at it and didn't see that

Comment: Mhm maybe it doesn't, I'm not sure. But a reload does not check the checkboxes, so I only see the main page of the shop with no category limitations.

Comment: Oh, that's a much harder item as you would have to ajax the setttings somewhere and then the reload would pull them back.  Using Back Button with AJAX settings causes lots of issues

Comment: Do you have any ideas how to do so? Convert selected checkboxes to a get variable with javascript and add it to url and then rebuild settings with jquery from url? It would be a lot of work, because I have a lot of settings on the page (price, category, collection, color...). It would be great if there is another solution.