# Javascript: disabling HTML Select option issue on browser back-button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

As in the title, I'm struggling with what I thought being a trivial issue: disabling an option from an HTML Select tag list when I click on an aforethought radio button.
My code does work, but when a user hits the browser back-button, my function doesn't get called anymore, so the previously disabled selector can now be chosen from the list. I'd prefer to avoid reloading the HTML page when I press the back-button using PHP, as advised in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645609/reload-the-page-on-hitting-back-button).

This is my Javascript code:

```
$(function () {
    $("#radioButton1").on("click", function () {
        $("#selector3").prop("disabled", false);
    });

    $("#radioButton2").on("click", function () {
        var selector = $("#selector3");

        selector.prop("disabled", true);
        selector.css("background", "#dddddd");

        $("#orderByList").val("1");
    });
});
```

Comment: you should probably save the user selection before changing the URL and check for saved value when the page is loading

Comment: But this will not solve my issue: pressing the back button uses the cached version of the web page, so I'm already saving the user selection. In my second page I've an home button: using it solves my issue. Still, the real problem comes up if a user choose to get back by the means of the aforementioned browser button.

Comment: Disable the select by default and then enable it with script when you hit the page.  If it's using a cached version of the page and not running scripts when you hit the back button then that will resolve your issue.

Comment: looking at this code it's hard to tell what could go wrong. Could you provide a working fiddle

Comment: I've found a Javascript solution. I'll post references in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a working solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43043658/4938112).

```
window.addEventListener("pageshow", function (event) {
    var historyTraversal = event.persisted || (typeof window.performance !== "undefined" && window.performance.navigation.type === 2);

    if ( historyTraversal ) {
        // Handle page restore.
        window.location.reload();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try using functions outside of the $(function () {}); block

```
<script>
$("#radioButton1").on("click", function () {
        $("#selector3").prop("disabled", false);
    });

    $("#radioButton2").on("click", function () {
        var selector = $("#selector3");

        selector.prop("disabled", true);
        selector.css("background", "#dddddd");

        $("#orderByList").val("1");
    });
</script>
```

Binding could be done in  tags only